# Javascript - Table data from column to column

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use Javascript (using react.js also) to make a simple converter program with preset values.

I need to:

1. Find a value in the first column matching the inputted value
2. Go along the row by one and take the value from this cell.

For example with this table,

[image]

I would like to enter "4" and get the values of Color, and maybe the other columns.

How could I do this and is there any easier way?

Comment: Could you provide some html code?

Comment: pastebin.com/Xc3KQgGa is sort of what I want. For example typing in "1" will return test1 or test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a function that takes 2 parameters. The first one is the value you want to compare with first cell in each row. The second one is the number of a column in which is the value you want to get.

```
function getCellByFirstRowValue(yourValue, columnNumber) {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if(row.cells[0].innerHTML == yourValue) {
            return row.cells[columnNumber].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

alert(getCellByFirstRowValue(1, 2)); // alerts "tests2"
alert(getCellByFirstRowValue(2, 1)); // alerts "tests3"
alert(getCellByFirstRowValue(3, 1)); // alerts "tests5"
```

Here is a link to a working JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxc7ut3u/